# Does an integral inequality imply a pointwise inequality?

Tags: integration, limsup-and-liminf, integral-inequality, pointwise-convergence, smooth-functions

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
Let $(f_n)_n \subset L^1(\R^N)$. Suppose that for any nonnegative function $\phi \in C_c^{\infty}(\R^N)$, we have:

$$
0 \leq \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int f_n \, \phi
$$

Can we conclude that $0 \leq \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x)$ for almost every $x \in \R^N$?

My first idea is to use the definition of $\liminf$ to get an estimate of $\inf_{m \geq N} \int f_m \, \phi \geq -\epsilon$, where $N$ depends on $\epsilon$. However, I'm not sure where to go from there.

Another fact that might be useful is that if $\int f \, \phi \geq 0$ for every nonnegative $\phi \in C_c^{\infty}(\R^N)$, then $f \geq 0$ a.e. (this is proven similarly to corollary 4.24 in Brezis' Functional Analysis). We might be able to use this for $f = \liminf f_n$, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: Bring everyting on the right side. Then your statement is equivalent to the following:

If for any nonnegative function $\phi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^N)$  holds:
$$0\leq \liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int g_n \phi$$

then $0\leq \liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} g_n(x)$ for almost every $x\in \mathbb{R}^N.$

Comment: Yes, I thought of bringing everything to one side; I mentioned that at the bottom of my post. My next guess was to use the definition to estimate the terms, but I'm not sure that gets me anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $N=1$, let us consider the functions
$$
f_n(x) := 
\begin{cases}
\sin(nx), & x\in [0,2\pi],\\
0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Then, for every $\phi\in C_c(\mathbb{R})$, by the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma one has $\lim_{n\to+\infty} \int f_n \phi = 0$.
On the other hand, $\liminf_n f_n(x) = -1$ for a.e. $x\in (0,2\pi)$ (and $0$ otherwise).

Answer (score 2):

On $\mathbb R,$ define the sequence $f_n$ as

$$-\mathbb {1}_{[0,1]},-\mathbb {1}_{[0,1/2]}, -\mathbb {1}_{[1/2,1]}, -\mathbb {1}_{[0,1/3]},-\mathbb {1}_{[1/3,2/3]},-\mathbb {1}i_{[2/3,1]},  \dots$$

Then $\int f_n\phi \to 0$ for every $\phi \in L^1,$ yet $\liminf f_n(x) = -1$ for every $x\in [0,1].$

With a little extra care we could get $\liminf f_n(x) = -1$ for every $x\in \mathbb R.$